# What is the most efficient way to construct training images from segmentation output?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, deep-learning, training-data, watershed

I want to make training images from watershed transformation output so that in each cell there will be a single image segment. How can I do this in the most efficient way?

More details:
suppose `L` is the output of watershed segmentation:

```
L =

 1     1     2
 1     0     2
 1     2     2
 0     0     2
```

- 0 is background
- 1 is segment number 1, 2 is segment number 2 and so on.

I want to construct a cell with two images, each one contain a segment:

```
cell1=

1     1 
1     0 
1     0 

cell2=

0     2 
0     2 
2     2
0     2
```

I know I can do it with some for loops and if conditions, however I need to have a solution with the best computation cost. Maybe Matlab has a bulit-in function for this task?

Comment: Sometimes for loops are not slow. Try, profile, improve. "Early optimization is the root of all evil!"

Comment: I agree with @AnderBiguri, and using a built-in function don't mean that this function doesn't use loops ! This is just a "black box".

Comment: in meanwhile I found a built-in solution myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with following one linner ;-)

```
U = regionprops(L, 'Image')
```

Comparison between solutions (L is a 1200x1600 pixel image):

```
>> tic;
for index=1:100
U = regionprops(L, 'Image');
end
toc;
```

Elapsed time is **20.138794** seconds.

```
>>tic;
for index=1:100
N = max(L(:)); %//number of segments
C = cell(N,1); %//create Cell Array
[height, width] = size(L); %//get dimensions of image

for target=1:N %//for each segment..

    %//search column-wise to get first and last column index
    col_start = ceil(find(L==target,1)/height);
    col_end = ceil(find(L==target,1,'last')/height);

    %//search row-wise to get first and last row index
    row_start = ceil(find(L.'==target,1)/width);
    row_end = ceil(find(L.'==target,1,'last')/width);

    T = L(row_start:row_end , col_start:col_end); %//image segment of bounding box
    T(T~=target) = 0; %//set non-targets to 0

    C{target} = T; %//add to cell array

end;
end
toc;
```

Elapsed time is **300.744868** seconds.

```
>> tic;
for index=1:100
u = unique(L(:));
B = arrayfun(@(x) removePadding(L, x)*2, u(2:end), 'UniformOutput', false);
end
toc;
```

Elapsed time is **182.193148** seconds.

Comment: Yes but is it quick? Measure against the solution from Lincoln. `regionprops` is a rather "heavy" function, so Id be interested whether it runs quickly.

Comment: Seems quick or you have simply a beast-machine compared to mine ;-))

Comment: You should run it like a few hundreds of times to make sure current load of your computer or some background tools won't influence the results. So do it as I did it above: `tic; for i=1:500 %HERE THE ACTUAL SOLUTION end; toc`

Comment: I made an update to my answer. The builtin function is not the best! but there is one point to consider: in the Lincon's answer, the number of segments is given, but in reality it has to be calculated so I doubt it can be much faster than the builtin.

Comment: Then replace `N` in Lincolns answer by `N = max(L(:))`? And also: I think it's possible to replace `u = unique(L(:));` in my answer by `u = 1:max(L(:))` as the region-index is stetic without any gap, i.e. it will contain all values to the max value because it is labeled like that from the watershed algorithm. But that won't change the runtime much. Maybe change it slightly and divide `toc/100` so you'd get the runtime of ONE iteration. One more thing to consider: the datasize can influence the different algorithms in different way.

Comment: One algorithm could be faster for small matrices, the other one faster for bigger matrices. So you should also give a `real` dataset for `L` instead of the small 4x3 matrix above :-) Then test it!!

Comment: all of the tests are on real example (1200x1600 pixels).

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for an efficient way, I think the following solution should work nicely. Although it uses 1 for-loop, it only loops `N` times where `N` is the `number of segments` in your watershed transformed output, which usually is very low for image segmentations (N=2 for your example).

```
N = max(L(:)); %//number of segments
C = cell(N,1); %//create Cell Array
[height, width] = size(L); %//get dimensions of image

for target=1:N %//for each segment..

    %//search column-wise to get first and last column index
    col_start = ceil(find(L==target,1)/height);
    col_end = ceil(find(L==target,1,'last')/height);

    %//search row-wise to get first and last row index
    row_start = ceil(find(L.'==target,1)/width);
    row_end = ceil(find(L.'==target,1,'last')/width);

    T = L(row_start:row_end , col_start:col_end); %//image segment of bounding box
    T(T~=target) = 0; %//set non-targets to 0

    C{target} = T; %//add to cell array

end
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I think a fair comparison between your answer and the others needs an automatic calculation of number of segments in the beginning of the code. Can you modify it?

Comment: @Woeitg I'll just add something like `length(unique(L))-1` or something.

Comment: this modification made your code to run very slow (see edition inside my answer)

Comment: @Woeitg I wasn't thinking. @tim is right, `N = max(L(:))` will probably be faster instead.

Comment: I update my answer. the result is improved, but not good enough to ibeat Matlab's builtin function.

Answer (score 1):

I have written here one **clean / short** solution, but I don't know whether it is quicker or slower then the one from Lincoln. Simply try yourself using `tic/toc`.

```
function A = removePadding(L, x) 
  A = (L==x); 
  A(all(A == 0, 2), :)=[]; 
  A(:, all(A == 0, 1))=[]; 
end

L = [1 1 2;1 0 2; 1 2 2; 0 0 2];
u = unique(L(:))
arrayfun(@(x) removePadding(L, x)*2, u(2:end), 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Will output:

```
ans =
{
  [1,1] =

     1   1
     1   0
     1   0

  [2,1] =

     0   2
     0   2
     2   2
     0   2

}
```

Attention: The function `removePadding` will remove all rows/columns which only contain zeros. That means it won't work if one region wouldn't be connected, because intermediate rows/cols would also be removed. But I think this won't happen in your case as watershed (IMO) will only return the same region-index (e.g. 1 for region 1) if the region is fully connected.

---

Speedtest:
First, L and my function is defined.
Now the test:

```
>> tic; 
for i = 1:1000
  u = unique(L(:));
  B = arrayfun(@(x) removePadding(L, x)*2, u(2:end), 'UniformOutput', false);
end
>> toc
Elapsed time is 4.89563 seconds.
```

Now you can copy this test-snippet and modify it to also check the speed of Lincolns calculation.

EDIT2: I defined Lincolns solution as `C = myFun(L)` and then run the speed test again:

```
>> tic;
>> for i = 1:1000
  B = myFun(L);
end
>> toc
Elapsed time is 1.01026 seconds.
```

Seems much faster :-) Even though using a for-loop.

Comment: tnx for answer. I also found a bulit-in solution myself that I sent as separate answer. elapsed time of your code in my pc is 0.532072 seconds ! for my own code, the elapsed  time is 0.018671 seconds. however I am not sure if I calculate elapsed time in correct way...